# Rx descriptor dma mapping in device driver what that actually means, Does it mean mapping of packets at physical NIC to struct object in memory

Tags: linux-device-driver, intel, dma, pci, realtek

I am going through realtek r8169 driver and but kind of stuck in this line

```
    tp->RxDescArray = dma_alloc_coherent(&pdev->dev, R8169_RX_RING_BYTES,
                     &tp->RxPhyAddr, GFP_KERNEL);
```

From the book Linux device driver, it just says it is `...Function handles both the allocation and the mapping of the buffer, ...arguments are device structure and the size of buffer needed`

What does that mean: allocation I could understanding but what is it mean by `mapping`

does this mean that what ever I have in pdev represented device's rx descriptor that same I will have in what returns from `dma_alloc_coherent` which is `tp->RxDescArray` a descriptor as a software object? tp->RxDescArray is of type `RxDesc` in the driver which is like following

```
    struct RxDesc {
        __le32 opts1;
        __le32 opts2;
        __le64 addr;
     };
```

if this is what mapping is: means whatever I have in pdev represented device rx decriptor on physical device that same I will have in  software object `tp->RxDescArray` is that what mapping means. then who define the structure of `RxDesc`, is this something included in datasheet. If it does then under which section? There are numerous sections in a datasheet. should it be more clearer
`

**Update**
Also like to know what does this line does

```
  tp->RxDescArray[NUM_RX_DESC - 1].opts1 |= cpu_to_le32(RingEnd);
```

tp->RxDescArray is of type RxDesc (not array of RxDesc) does this statement mark the `end` of variable RxDescArray means what every next will happen will after that `end` address

**Update 2**

I need info on if I have a datasheet lets say from intel E1000E driver, or r8169 driver from RealTek, then how I create create Rx Descrptor structure, in above code it does something like this

```
    struct RxDesc {
    __le32 opts1;
    __le32 opts2;
    __le64 addr;
     }
```

what is opts1, opts2 and addr? how author of this driver got this idea of creating this structure. Only he had was datasheet with many hex values

Comment: **DMA mapping** is a translation between CPU address space (_virtual address_) and Device address space (_bus address_).

Comment: Can u please take a loot at the update question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DMA accesses are translated by the IOMMU, which on Intel systems is described in the [Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d) specification](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-virtualization-technology-for-directed-io-architecture-specification.html).

The function dma_alloc_coherent allocates memory and introduces a mapping into the DMA page tables so that the memory is accessible to the device. The address returned is not the virtual or physical address of the memory, but is a I/O virtual address (IOVA), which the device can use to access memory. The IOVA is translated by the IOMMU into the physical memory address when the device performs DMA.

The IOMMU prevents any device from accessing physical memory that hasn't been mapped into that specific device's I/O address space.

Comment: So for IOMMU do I need to enable physical layer in RTL r8169 driver it register `mdio: phy in mac` and initializes physical layer by assigning `mii_bus->read=someting_function` ns `mii_bis->write=something_write_function`. and in initialize phy function it simply does `phy_write_paged` and `writel`,etc. So Do I need to register and initialize phy to began with MMIO/DMA/ or any interaction with device

Comment: Initializing the phy doesn’t have anything to do with DMA. But you have to initialize the phy before you can send or receive anything on the network.

Comment: So is that mean I can not write data or values to nic register using `writel`  if I have not register or initialized phy

Comment: The phy has **nothing** to do with CPU accesses to the NIC registers. You seem to be **very** confused about how a NIC works and continuing to ask questions here isn’t the best way for you to gain an understanding. Also your question continues to expand from the original question about DMA mappings into completely unrelated areas about how a NIC works. Stack  overflow tries to keep each question on a single topic.

Comment: ok I think I am getting it, so mdio/media access controller/phy (from OSI model) have to be in driver to make driver connect to a network from `you have to initialize the phy before you can send or receive anything on the network` for this, I also see it need to configured to NIC device register. it is simply done this using writing to device like using `writel/writeb/writew` family of functions. There is mdio implemented and that requires I/O writing/configuring to device for `phy/mdio`. This is from code of drivers like `E1000E`/`r8169` drivers.

Comment: final question. So in `init_phy` from r8169 it uses these functions: , `phy_write_paged` so there are phy registers as well. Are these phy registers exists for implementing OSI physical layer  and functions like `phy_write_paged` after execution they write to where? these function calls are in phy_init and called when device go up in open function of netdev_ops

Answer (score 0):

RingEnd marks the end of the ring buffer for the NIC. So that NIC DMA engine knows where to jump to the start of the ring buffer.

Comment: Why end of ring buffer had to be recorded? do u means NIC card can have no idea about the software object `struct RxDesc` which variable starts where and ends where,Please clarify

Comment: How's the NIC supposed to know the size of the ring buffer you set up in the driver? That's what the ring end marker is good for.

Comment: Does every RxDesc element pointed in tp->RxDescArray pointer has to be marked by ring end marker like `tp->RxDescArray[NUM_RX_DESC - 1].opts1 |= cpu_to_le32(RingEnd);` ?

Comment: Of course not. How many ends can a ring buffer have? You ask a number of low-level questions that show you miss the basics. Therefore I'd recommend you first understand the big picture and concepts like DMA descriptor ring buffers.
Instead of asking what a function does, look at the code and where and in which context the function is used.